# Adding Float value in jQuery

Tags: javascript

Adding  float values using jQuery

used code:

result variables:

```
subtotal = 4.6;
tax = 2.3;

Total = parseFloat(subtotal)+parseFloat(tax);
```

i got result 6.8999999999999995... why it not returning the correct value 6.9

Comment: I am scared of people who are thinking jQuery is everything!

Comment: @Exception what you thinking?

Comment: I can't see any little tiny bit of jquery in the above javascript code

Comment: @Dhamu The code you have written is JavaScript. Before including jQuery, try to understand what jQuery is.

Comment: @Dhamu you don't use jQuery here. Anyway you should read about what `float` are and why the result you see is correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use **[toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** like

```
Total =Total.toFixed(1);
```

Or `Simply`,

```
Total = (parseFloat(subtotal)+parseFloat(tax)).toFixed(1);
```

Comment: @Tats_innit see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: ++1 bruv `:)` lol time for me to sleep

Comment: @Tats_innit **Goodnight** :)